# Error while running React project in localhost

Tags: reactjs, npm, web-development-server

I cloned a repo from azure devOps into a folder in my D drive. And then i ran the command npm start to open my project in localhost 3000. it shows the following error:
Any idea how to fix it?

```
D:\>cd HWS


Cloning into 'Frontend'...
remote: Azure Repos
remote: Found 1081 objects to send. (200 ms)
Receiving objects: 100% (1081/1081), 774.29 KiB | 405.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (645/645), done.

    D:\HWS>
    D:\HWS>npm start
    npm ERR! code ENOENT
    npm ERR! syscall open
    npm ERR! path D:\HWS\package.json
    npm ERR! errno -4058
    npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\HWS\package.json'
    npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
    npm ERR! enoent
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\Intel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-07T15_52_13_775Z-debug.log
    
    D:\HWS>
```

Comment: Check whether you are in the correct path that `package.json` contains.

Answer (score 1):

you need to run `npm start` from Frontend folder not from `HWS`. So just add `cd Frontend` command after you cloned the repository